# add new record to model that has relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails so do not expect super smart question.

- I have student M-V-C. The student can have multiple majors.
- I have Majors M-v_c which linked to the student in 1 to many relation.
- I successfully created student record using "accepts_nested_attributes_for".

Now I can see the student record in the show html.

the question:
- How can I add new major to the student? I don't want to change the existing majors I need to add new one.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First find the user or the users you want to add to the new major, and then you just have to create the major.

I don't know which way your association is. So I did some example code for both ways:

STUDENT < 1 : n > MAJORS (a student has many majors)

```
student = Student.find( student_id )
student.major = Major.new
student.save
```

MAJOR < 1 : n > STUDENTS (a major has many students)

```
student = Student.find( student_id )
major = Major.new
major.students << student
major.save
```

pick the one which suits your needs

Comment: you are superhero thanks. should I add add_major  action and fix the route or there is a better way?

Comment: If you used `rails generate scaffold` to generate your files, you should have a Major#new function. This should be the perfect place. Just add a field for the user and you should be ready... Know what I mean?